# Why do I get an "attempted to call function imagecreatefrompng" error while gd is enabled?

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to save an image on my local server from an url with the following code :

```
private function getDragontailImage() {
   /* load image from the url */
   $img = imagecreatefrompng('https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.25.1/img/champion/Aatrox.png');

   /* Save the image on my local server but the execution actualy does not reach this point */
   file_put_contents('my/local/path', $img);
}
```

Unfortunatly the following error happens :

> Attempted to call function "imagecreatefrompng" from namespace
> "App\Controller".

This namespace is indeed the one where I'm calling the function. From what I understand, this error often occurs when grammar mistakes are done. I compared my syntax to the one in [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng) but I still can't see what I did wrong.

So far, I've also checked theses points :

- My **composer.json** file contains `"ext-gd": "*"` - which is needed for the function.
- My **php.ini** file has `allow_url_fopen = On`  in order to enable the use of an url as parameter.
- In my **php infos**, I can read that GD support and PNG support are enabled.
- I've restart my local server after theses changes.

I dont know if it's an important information but I use this command line for running my local server :

> php -S localhost:8000 -t public/

What did I miss ?

Comment: Maybe try tu use `$img = \imagecreatefrompng('https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.25.1/img/champion/Aatrox.png');` to force PHP namespace resolution to look in global one.

Comment: The result of your `phpinfo();` could help.

Comment: @LeviathanCalumet The `\imagecreatefrompng` tip did not work.
Concerning the `phpinfo();` which information would be pertinent ? Btw, I noticed that the gd section is not present when I run the function but it is when I consult the "php infos" tab from MAMP. Does it mean gd is not correctly installed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a specialist of MAMP or any (L/W/M/X)AMP version but maybe you should resolve your issue this way :

In your `phpinfo();` execution result you should have an entry for Configuration File (php.ini) Path from where a php.ini is resolved.

Then in this php.ini file should be a commented line such as `;extension=gd.so`. You will have to uncomment this line (remove the semicolon) to make `gd` to be active.